# Error in displaying large sized CSV file in Angular

Tags: angular, csv, file-upload, papaparse

The size of my CSV file is 500MB having 700k rows and when I display it using the below code, Chrome says,

> paused before potential out of memory crash

My Angular code, app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as Papa from 'papaparse';

let obj: AppComponent;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    name = 'Angular csv file parser example';
    dataList: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        obj = this;
    }

    onChange(files: File[]) {

        if (files[0]) {

            console.log(files[0]);
            Papa.parse(files[0], {
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: (result, file) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    this.dataList = result.data;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: At what point does it crash? On parsing, or displaying the results? If the problem is in displaying data, then you could try features like virtual scroll. If an attempt to parse it is enough to kill the browser, then you simply can't work with that large chunks of data. Paginating would solve the problem.

Comment: @mbojko Yes pagination did solve the problem, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

f the problem is in displaying data, then you could try features like virtual scroll and Pagination